# titleformat: left margin numbering and centered body

Tags: titlesec

TLDR: How to create a title with leftmargin numbering (right justified) and centered body?

right now I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\Huge\bfseries\center}
{\huge\thechapter}
{20pt}
{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
\lipsum[1] 

\end{document}
```

this creates the complete chapter label, both the numbering and the body to be centered together as can be seen here.

[image: progress]

How do I make the numbering on the left margin (I tried to replace [block] for [leftmargin] but this puts the whole title into the left margin, both the numbering and the body) and the body of the title to be centered alone (without the numbering). (Also make the numbering right justified once inside the left margin of the page.)

The desired result is something like this:

[image: desired result]

(Note: in this desired result picture, the test header body is not centered properly, but I do want it to be centered properly.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please complete your code to make it compilable, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, including all relevant packages which are required to reproduce what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a new `\mychapter` command with a `\parbox` and I've modified the 
`\titleformat` with a `\makebox`.

I've left commented what I used for the alignment tests.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}% for testing purpose
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\framebox[\linewidth][c]{#1}}}% \framebox for testing purpose
\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\centering #1}}}

\begin{document}
    \titleformat{\chapter}
    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
    {}
    {}
    {}

    \tableofcontents

    \titleformat{\chapter}
    {\Huge\bfseries}
    %{\huge\hspace{-50pt}\parbox[t]{50pt}{\framebox[30pt][r]{\thechapter}}}% \framebox for testing purpose
    {\huge\hspace{-50pt}\parbox[t]{50pt}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\thechapter}}}
    {0pt}
    {}  

    \mychapter{Short chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Long long long long long long chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Short chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Long long long long long long chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Short chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Long long long long long long chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Short chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Long long long long long long chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Short chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

    \mychapter{Long long long long long long chapter title}
    \lipsum[1] 

\end{document}
```

A chapter with a short title:

[image]

A (two-digit-numbered) chapter with a long title:

[image]

For completeness, I've also centered the title of the ToC, but I left the chapter list left aligned:

[image]